# C++ rand() each number only once

Tags: c++, random, numbers, srand

I need something like rand() but I want each number only once.

In example I have 10 ".txt" files that are named as numbers (1-10).
I want to read what is inside there and cout it, but randomly.

I don't want 1.txt -> 2.txt -> 3.txt -> ...
but something random like

5.txt -> 4.txt -> 1.txt -> ...

and each number should only come up once

Is there an "easy" way to do this?

```
string Path = "./Questions_Niko/" + random + ".txt";
```

Comment: If the true application of this is to iterate over files with a predictable name format (i.e. {number}.txt, you can use a regular expression to suss out the files you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches. For example you can use standard algorithm `std::random_shuffle` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

int main()
{
   int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

   std::random_shuffle( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

   for ( int i : a )
   {
      //  some stuff
   }
}
```

The other way is to use standard class `std::bitset` and set the corresponding bit in the set for already selected number.

Answer (score 6):

Create a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of the numbers you want and use [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Then iterate over the vector in order.

Comment: This is the right idea, but please use [`shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead of `random_shuffle`. There's even an example of exactly what the OP wants on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hashmap of each result. If it does exist regenerate it.

Answer (score 0):

`std::random_shuffle` likely suits your needs, but if you can't/ don't want to, you can borrow [mshuffle:](http://solitairelaboratory.com/mshuffle.txt%20%22mshuffle')

```
int mix[10];
int swap;
for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
    int j = rand() % i;
    swap = mix[j];
    mix[j] = mix[i];
    mix[i] = swap;
}
```

Assuming you've called `srand()` first, this mixes up the array named `mix`. It need not be an array of `int`s.

Answer (score -1):

Using `srand()` will solve your problem

```
//Randomize seed
srand(time(NULL));

for(i to size)
    Arr[i]=rand()%size
```